# Can the screen be rotated on the Nexus 7?

Tags: nexus-7

I've noticed that physically turning the screen does not rotate the image on the Nexus 7.  Is there any way to rotate the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen can be rotated via software by running /usr/bin/xrotate. There are currently some issues with this method, but it is being worked on. There are future plans to tie this to the accelerometer, but this is not working quite yet.

Comment: can you explain in more detail, the latest image I installed on nexus 7 does not have the file mentioned.

Comment: I bet you are not talking about ubuntu-touch...